# Prime Number theorem and the prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Could someone please help me understand this proof given in an article by William Miller. It is supposed to follow from the prime number theorem that given $A(x)$ the sum of all primes less than or equal to $x$ and $\theta(x)$  the sum of the logarithm of all primes less than or equal to $x$,

$$A(x)\sim \frac{x^2}{2\log x} \ \ \ \rm and \ \ \ \theta(x) \sim x,$$

the following identity is used:

$$\theta(x) = \int_1^x \log(t)\mathrm{d}(\pi(t)),$$

where $\pi(t)$ is the prime counting function. I don't understand why this is. 
Here $\sim$ means asymptotic to i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$.

Comment: Could you give a link to this article you speak of, please?

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/115230/19341)?

Answer (score 5):

The notation
$$\int \log(t)\ d(\pi(t))$$
is an example of the [Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_integral). Some like this (I don't)
when discussing summation, as integrating with a step function $f(t)$
inside the $d$ notation is essentially a summation. Here $\pi(t)$
is constant, save at prime values of $t$ where it jumps by $1$. This means
that
$$\int_a^b g(t)\ d(\pi(t))=\sum_{p\ \mathrm{prime}}g(p)\times 1.$$
Here the summation is over all primes in the interval from $a$ to $b$
(I can't remember whay you do about the endpoints; one reason I don't
like the notation). If you like you can think that
$$\int_a^b g(t)\ d(\pi(t))=\int_a^b g(t)\pi'(t)\ dt$$
where $\pi'$ is seen as a generalized function, so as a bunch of delta-functions
at the primes. Again one has to do the right thing (or is it the left thing? :-))
at the endpoints.