# Summing over General Functions of Primes and an Application to Prime $\zeta$ Function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, prime-numbers

Along the lines of thought given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49434/19341), is it in general possible to substitute a summation over a function $f$ of primes like the following:
$$
\sum_{p\le x}f(p)=\int_2^x f(t) d(\pi(t))\tag{1}
$$
and further
$$
\int_2^x f(t) d(\pi(t))=f(t)\pi(t)\biggr|_2^{x}-\int_2^{x}f'(t)\pi(t)dt\tag{2}.
$$

> If it's possible only for some cases, how can one specify them? *answered in the comments*

Let's continue from $(2)$ with an representation of the prime counting function:
$$
\pi(t) = \operatorname{R}(t^1) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(t^{\rho}) \tag{3}
$$
with $    \operatorname{R}(u) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \mu (n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(u^{1/n})$ (the so-called Riemann's ${\rm R}$ Function, see *e.g.* $(11)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html)) and $\rho$ running over **all** the zeros (trivial and non-trivial) of $\zeta$ function. $\operatorname{li}(\cdot)$ is the [logarithmic integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html).

So we have 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&=&f(t)\pi(t)\biggr|_2^{x}-\int_2^{x}f'(t)\pi(t)dt\\
&=&f(t)\left(\operatorname{R}(t^1) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(t^{\rho})\right)\biggr|_2^{x}
-\int_2^{x}f'(t)\left(\operatorname{R}(t^1) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(t^{\rho})\right)dt \phantom{somemorerspace}\\
&\phantom{AA}&\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (n)}{n}\Big\{\left[f(t)\left( \sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}} (-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}} \operatorname{li}(t^{z/n})\right)\right]_2^{x}\\
&&- \int_2^{x}f'(t)\left( \sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}} (-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}} \operatorname{li}(t^{z/n})\right)dt\Big\}\\
&\phantom{AA}&\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (n)}{n}\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}\left\{\left[f(t)\left(   \operatorname{li}(t^{z/n})\right)\right]_2^{x} -
\int_2^{x}f'(t)\left(  \operatorname{li}(t^{z/n})\right)dt\right\}\hskip0.9in(4)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where I tried to combine the sum a little without introducing to much confusion by using 
$$
(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}=
\cases{
+1&$ \text{if } z=1$\\
-1&$ \text{if } z=\rho$\\
}
$$

Now, what if we just take an approximation $\tilde{\pi}(t)$, where the sums over $n$ and $\rho$ are truncated. Is this approach still valid? I'm worried because $\tilde{\pi}(t)$ might not be monotone, which is a prerequisite of the [Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration). 
Let's work out the last integral, by parts:
We use
$$
\int_2^{x}f'(t) \operatorname{li}(t^{w})dt
=\left[ f(t)\operatorname{li}(t^{w}) \right]_2^x - \int_2^x \frac{f(t)wt^{w-1}}{\ln(t^w)}dt
\tag{5}
$$
which gives a nice result when $f(t)=t^{-s}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49434/19341):
$$
\int_2^{x}(-st^{-s-1}) \operatorname{li}(t^{w})dt
=\left[ t^{-s}\operatorname{li}(t^{w}) \right]_2^x - \int_2^x \frac{t^{-s}t^{w-1}}{\ln(t)}dt
=\left[ t^{-s}\operatorname{li}(t^{w}) \right]_2^x - \left[{\rm li}(t^{w-s})\right]^x_2.
$$

So overall we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (n)}{n}\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}\left\{\left[f(t)  \operatorname{li}(t^{z/n})\right]_2^{x}-
\left[ f(t)\operatorname{li}(t^{z/n}) \right]_2^x +\int_2^x \frac{zf(t)t^{z/n-1}}{n\ln(t^{z/n})}dt \right\}\\
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (n)}{n}\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}\left\{\int_2^x \frac{f(t)t^{z/n-1}}{\ln(t)}dt \right\}\tag{6}\\
$$
and in the special case $f(t)=t^{-s}$ this simplifies to
$$
P_\color{red}x(\color{blue}s)=\sum_{p<\color{red}x} \frac{1}{p^s} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu (n)}{n}\sum_{z\in\{1,\rho\}}(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}
\left[
{\rm li}(t^{\frac zn-\color{blue}s})
\right]^{\color{red}x}_2
\tag{7}
$$

(for the interested reader: the story continues [here...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280984/19341))

If anybody could confirm this, it would be ever so cool.

Thanks for your help and your time for reading all this,

Comment: Under some mild conditions on $f$ and assuming that $\pi(t)$ is right-continuous, i.e. 
$$
\pi(t) = \#\{\text{primes }p:p\leq t\}
$$ 
the integral here is well-defined in the [Lebesgue-Stieltjes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) sense. See the integration by parts formula in the linked article.

Comment: @Ilya Thanks a lot. A $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}$ in front of the sum/integral would also not hurt, I think/hope?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If you mean
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sum\limits_{p\leq x}f(p) = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\int\limits_0^tf(t)d\pi(t)
$$
then it holds: you have just both functions the same at each $x\geq 1$. Provided that, say $f(t)$ is finite and measurable on any interval $[1,x]$

Comment: @Ilya I would be very glad, if you could have a look at the updated version of my question...

Comment: Isn't $\tilde \pi$ at least one time differentiable?

Comment: For the integration w.r.t. $\tilde \pi$?

Comment: @Ilya yes. I mean the wiki page says I need a monotone function and $\tilde \pi$ isn't. It has wiggles...ok it also says : ...$g : [a,b] → R$ is of bounded variation in $[a,b]$ and right-continuous.., Does $\tilde \pi$ fulfill this? Sorry for asking basic questions but I'm a beginner...

Comment: Ok, there are different kinds of integrals but the wast majority of them agrees that $\int_0^t f(s)\mathrm dg(s)$ exists at least whenever $f$ is continuous, $g$ is $C^1$. Moreover, the also give the same value to this integral.

Comment: Look, you asked already two versions of this question, both of them in the form "can we integrate?". The answers were: yes. Now, you have the 3rd question in the same post "can anybody verify that?". Isn't it too much for the very same post, especially taken into account that you already got answers to previous two version of it. I don't welcome it, so -1. People usually ask separate questions in such cases.

Comment: @Ilya ok maybe I've overdone it...sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your time.

Comment: @draks...$$\sum_{p\leq n}f(p)=\sum_{k=1}^n\omega(k) \sum_{j=1}^{[\frac{n}{k}]}f(jk)\mu(j)$$

Comment: @Ethan +1 Is $\omega(k)$ the number of distinct prime factors of $k$? How could it help solving my question? Where did you get that and/or how to prove it?

Comment: Yes it is the number of distinct prime factors of k, and the formula is mostly for show, there are more useful functional equations but they require more restrictions on your function f(x), if you put some more restrictions on your function much better results can be obtained, though if its monotonic $$\sum_{p\leq n} f(p)$$ ' tends' to be asymptotic to $$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{f(k)}{ln(k)}$$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function $f$ is smooth and compactly supported then the formula you are looking for already exists, and is called the "explicit formula". See for example Lemma 1 in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511092.

If you want to apply this lemma in the direction "primes to zeros" then you should "swap the hats" over $h$. Basically, once you have specified $\hat{h}$ to be a smooth compact function of your choice, the resulting function $h$ will be entire and you will be able to apply the lemma 1 to $h$, getting the desired formula a sum over the primes weighted by $\hat{h}$.

Comment: hmm, so you say that i. $f$ could be $t^{-s}$  and ii. $(-1)^{1-\delta_{1z}}
\left\{
\left[
{\rm li}(t^{\frac zn-\color{blue}s})
\right]^{\color{red}x}_2
-\left[t^{-\color{blue}s}\operatorname{li}(t^{\frac zn}) \right]_2^\color{red}x
\right\}$ corresponds to $h$ right? If not could you work it out a bit, please? and +1 for the ref.

Comment: Maybe you could also help solving [this follow-on puzzle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/280984/19341) I would be glad, if you could have a look...

Answer (score 1):

An effective form of the Riemann explicit formula is
$$\psi(n+1/2) =\sum_{p^k \le n+1/2} \log p = n+1/2-  \sum_{|\Im(\rho)| < T} \frac{(n+1/2)^\rho}{\rho}-\log 2\pi + \mathcal{O}(\frac{n \log n}{T})$$
(where $n+1/2$ is for avoiding the Gibbs phenomenom at integer values)

Thus
$$\sum_{p^k \le N} f(p^k) \log p = \sum_{n = 1}^N f(n) (1-  \sum_{|\Im(\rho)| < T} \frac{(n+1/2)^\rho-(n-1/2)^\rho}{\rho}) + \mathcal{O}(\sum_{n=1}^N |f(n)|\frac{n \log n}{T})$$
The same idea can be adapted to explicit formulas for $J(x) = \sum_{p^k \le x} \frac{1}{k}$ and $\pi(x) = \sum_{p \le x } 1 = \sum_{m=1}^x \frac{\mu(m)}{m} J(x^{1/m})$

Summing by parts you'll improve the error term to $\mathcal{O}( |f(N)|\frac{N \log N}{T})+\mathcal{O}(\sum_{n=1}^N |f(n)-f(n+1)|\frac{n \log n}{T})$