# Generating function for the characteristic function of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, generating-functions

What do we know about the generating function of $\chi(n)$ ([A010051](http://oeis.org/A010051))
$$
  f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \chi(n)x^n = \sum_{p\text{ prime}} x^p
$$
for $\chi(n)$ the characteristic function of the primes:

$$
  \chi(n) = 
     \begin{cases}
        1, & \text{if $n$ is prime}\\
        0, & \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
$$
Are there some references I could take a look at?

Comment: Maybe you are interested in this: [Summing over General Functions of Primes](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/115230/19341)

Answer (score 6):

This is essentially the inverse Mellin transform of the [Prime zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function). Perhaps you'd like to look in that direction.

Comment: So you say that $\left\{\mathcal{M}^{-1}P\right\}(x) = f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} x^{-s} P(s)\, ds, $ where $P(s)$ is Prime $\zeta$?

Comment: I'm really interested. Could you answer to my comment?

Comment: @draks...: Sorry for overlooking your question the first time. If $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$, then $\mathcal M(f(e^{-t}))(s) = \Gamma(s)L(f,s)$, where $L(f, s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$.

Answer (score 2):

We know that, $\chi(n)$ can be represented as $\pi(n)-\pi(n-1)$.